# how can I set colour to particular text and on click listener in single textview

Tags: android

I am new to this android development ...I was wondering how these **#tag** works in **Instagram and other** ...can any one know how to do that ..[image]

look in my database tree ..over here I have description and tag ...
I am getting description to text view ...
**what I want is if `description.contains("#jb")`.. I want the text  `#jb` to be in blue colour and I want that `#jb` text should have `onclicklistner()`**

please help me guys I have tried but it makes the whole text blue I want the particular "#tag" text to be blue ..how can I do this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this library](https://github.com/danylovolokh/HashTagHelper) by which you can set ***custom colors and click listener***

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.danylovolokh:hashtag-helper:1.1.0'
}
```

To get all hashtags from the text.

```
// get all hashtags with "#", example: "#blueeyes"
List<String> allHashTags = mTextHashTagHelper.getAllHashTags(true);

// get all hashtags without "#", example: "blueeyes"
List<String> allHashTags = mTextHashTagHelper.getAllHashTags(false);
```

It will give you hashtag and also provide you **click listener**

```
mTextHashTagHelper = HashTagHelper.Creator.create(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), new HashTagHelper.OnHashTagClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onHashTagClicked(String hashTag) {

    }
  });

  // pass a TextView or any descendant of it (incliding EditText) here.
  // Hash tags that are in the text will be hightlighed with a color passed to HasTagHelper
  mTextHashTagHelper.handle(mHashTagText);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Spannable String](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString)

To change the color for particular Character sequence you can use [Forground Color Span](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan)

And

To add click listeners you can use [Clickable Span](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan)

Comment: thanks a lot man...but I confused about this ......`SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Text with a foreground color span");
string.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 12, 28, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);` as in google docs

Comment: I am confused in this code  `string.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 12, 28, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);`  what is the 12 ,28 means

Comment: You have to provide `start_index` and `end_index` from the String, on which you want to apply particular span. Which are 12 and 28 in your example